# Oracle Listener refused the connection error: ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

While connecting to the database, it works for initial 5 minutes and gets disconnected with below error:

```
Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
  (CONNECTION_ID=)
```

When the database is restarted, it again works good for 5 minutes and gets disconnected again with the same error.

Comment: does `lsnrctl status` on the server show the expected service_name? is the database instance still running?